# Return the index of first type which matches a continuous sequence in an array

Tags: java, algorithm

My objects looks like below: Note this isn't homework but a web project I'm doing on my own. So help will be appreciated!

```
enum size { small, big; }

Class Controller
{
    size sizeType;
}

Class square extends shape
{
    int num = 1;
}

Class circle extends shape
{
  int num=2;
  size size = size.Small;
}

void method()
{
    Controller[] sizes = new Controller[n];
    // e.g. shape = {small, big, small, small, big}

    Shape circle = new Shape();
    /* Find 2 'small' continuous circles 
       OR find 'size' based on the num value 
       (circle has 2 but should be able to accept 
       any integer = num declared in the shape class */

    // RETURN occurrence of first such index for e.g. 2 as found in 2,3    
}
```

Comment: Where is your `Shape` class?

Comment: And where is the `type` enum?

Comment: The question is filling the commented portion, return occurrence of first such index.

Comment: I corrected, it only has size enum and not type. Shape is just an abstract class that doesn't do anything at the moment.

Comment: Also, your naming conventions are all wrong, please correct them.  Also correct your indentation.  And finally, spelling the `class` keyword as `Class` is WRONG, and won't even compile.  Please fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem with your code:  you are totally mangling the object hiearchy.

First things first, here are some small corrections, based on my guesses as to what you intended:

```
enum SizeType { SMALL, BIG; }

class Shape {
    SizeType size;
}

class Square extends Shape {
    int num = 1;
}

class Circle extends Shape {
    int num = 2;
    SizeType size = SizeType.SMALL;
}

int findShapeSequence(Shape[] shapes) {
    // TODO find the first instance of a repeated size value in the array,
    // and return the index of the first of the shapes whose size repeats.   
}
```

Now that this is cleared away, it should be fairly easy for you to figure out how to actually do what you want your method to do.

Comment: How do I find 2 circle continuous shape sequences of type small ?

Comment: @Phoenix That's your job to figure out.  I'll help you, but only if you actually make an attempt to solve it yourself first.  HINT: use a `for` loop to iterate through the shapes, and compare the `size` value of the current `Shape` with that of the next.

Comment: but the num of shapes can be 1/2/3 it isn't fixed. For e.g. if there are 5 .. Is there an easier way to do it ?

Comment: So are you trying to detect runs in the `size` members of the classes, or in the `num` members of the classes?

Comment: "size" field in the shape class can be changed by user. Currently i have set it to "small". The length of run sequence will be as defined by the "num" field in individual shape classes. So for e.g. if the user selects circle (since currently it is small) the function will return two (=num) small sizes.